# Прямая речь заканчивается сокращением с точкой. Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь, сокращения

*«Будут проведены работы по реконструкции стадиона, самого здания и т. д.» — сказал Иван Иванов.*
Ставить ли в этом предложении запятую после закрывающей кавычки?

Answer (score 2):

> **6.** При сочетании разных знаков препинания с кавычками действует ряд правил:
> **1)** перед закрывающей кавычкой не ставится точка, запятая, тире, двоеточие, точка с запятой; эти знаки возможны лишь после кавычек... Точка возможна лишь при сокращении слова, тогда она оказывается внутри выделяемого кавычками компонента: *Здесь было две статьи: одна — Латунского, а другая — подписанная буквами «Н. Э.».*

[Сочетание знаков препинания и последовательность их расположения; комбинации знаков в сложных конструкциях](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-033.htm) (Н. С. Валгина, В. Н. Светлышева)

У [Розенталя](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827552.html) (§ 66.4):

> Точка ставится после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова: *В объявлении было сказано:
> «Появилась в продаже дачная мебель: столы, стулья, диваны и т. д.».*

Это как раз наш случай: точка в конце прямой речи относится не ко всему предложению, а только к "и т. д." (то есть к сокращению), поэтому запятая после закрывающих кавычек ставится на общих основаниях.
**«Будут проведены работы по реконструкции стадиона, самого здания и т. д.», — сказал Иван Иванов.**

Стоит отметить, что *такое* написание возможно лишь в том случае, если говорящий действительно произнес "и т. д.". (Заметьте: опять точка внутри кавычек!)

Вот выдержка из [**статьи**](https://www.vesti.ru/article/2553480) (оформлена как цитата):

> *"Много пилотных проектов, некоторые только назову. Это развитие Шерегеша – ведущего горнолыжного центра Кузбасса, создание яхтенного курорта в Балаклавской бухте в Севастополе и т.д.", – сказал Путин.*

Думаю, что цитирование нужно было оформить таким образом (В. В. Путин не произносил ни "и так далее", ни "и т. д."):

> "Много пилотных проектов, некоторые только назову. Это развитие Шерегеша — ведущего горнолыжного центра Кузбасса, создание яхтенного курорта в Балаклавской бухте в Севастополе..." — сказал Путин.

Answer (score 0):

Не ставить. (Кстати, после знаков вопроса или восклицания и многоточия запятую в таких случаях тоже не ставят.)