# Сокращающая точка в кавычках или переносится?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, сокращения, сокращающая-точка

`Он сказал: «В семейство кошачьих входят: ягуары, львы, тигры, леопарды и т. д.».`

`Он сказал: «В семейство кошачьих входят: ягуары, львы, тигры, леопарды и т. д».`

Сокращающая точка поглощается другой точкой или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ставятся обе точки.

[**Кавычки и другие знаки**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178) (справочник Розенталя):

> **Точка** повторяется после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова: *В объявлении было сказано: «Появилась в продаже дачная мебель: столы, стулья, диваны и т. д.».*

Answer (score 2):

Правильно с точкой внутри кавычек (она никуда не девается):

*Он сказал: «В семейство кошачьих входят: ягуары, львы, тигры, леопарды и **т. д.».***

Розенталь ([Кавычки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178#pp178)), наш случай:

> **Точка** повторяется после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова: *В объявлении было сказано: «Появилась в продаже дачная мебель: столы, стулья, диваны и т. д.».*

«Это случилось в 2023 **г.».**
«В тот день ко мне приехал **К.».**
«... и т. д. **и т. п.».**
«... **и др.».**

Вот здесь есть дополнительная информация и примеры.
[Прямая речь заканчивается сокращением с точкой. Ставится ли запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466986/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F/467000#467000)